# MongoDB Nested Search with multiple inclusive Criteras

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb, search

In MongoDB, Consider various instances of Person Documents structured as follow:

**JSON:**

```
{
"PersonId": 100, 
"FirstName": "Joe Louis", 
"LastName": "Jordan", 
"Roles": [
            {
                "Id": 93031, 
                "RoleType": 1, 
                "Organization": {
                                    "Id": 2, 
                                    "NameEn": "X",
                                    "NameFr": "X"
                                }
            }
            {
                "Id": 93031, 
                "RoleType": 2, 
                "Organization": {
                                    "Id": 3, 
                                    "NameEn": "Y",
                                    "NameFr": "Y"
                                }
            }
                            {
                "Id": 93031, 
                "RoleType": 3, 
                "Organization": {
                                    "Id": 2, 
                                    "NameEn": "X",
                                    "NameFr": "X"
                                }
            }
            {
                "Id": 93031, 
                "RoleType": 4, 
                "Organization": {
                                    "Id": 3, 
                                    "NameEn": "Y",
                                    "NameFr": "Y"
                                }
            }
                            {
                "Id": 93031, 
                "RoleType": 5, 
                "Organization": {
                                    "Id": 2, 
                                    "NameEn": "X",
                                    "NameFr": "X"
                                }
            }
        ]}
```

I want to Retrieve all the person having roles of type 1 AND 3 for which the nested organization is X (id:2)

I am trying the following but its not quite working. I need to be able to filter on the person having all the requested role, and then check if the Organization is 2 among the matching role documents

**VB.NET:**

```
Dim f As FilterDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.All(Of Integer)("Roles.RoleId", {1, 3}) And Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of Integer)("Roles.$.Organization.Id", 2)
```

**MongoShell:**

```
db.test.find({$and: [{'Roles.RoleId': {$all:  [1, 3]}}, {'Roles.Organization.Id': 2}]})
```

This is an inclusive query. All the criteras must be true. I a person has Role 3 but not for Organization 2, I don't want it

Is this possible in a single query?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my queries work... My actual data was bad.

VB.NET

```
Dim f As FilterDefinition(Of BsonDocument) = Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.All(Of Integer)("Roles.RoleId", {1, 3}) And Builders(Of BsonDocument).Filter.Eq(Of Integer)("Roles.$.Organization.Id", 2)
```

MongoShell

```
db.test.find({$and: [{'Roles.RoleId': {$all:  [1, 3]}}, {'Roles.Organization.Id': 2}]})
```